# Relation between two select tags in html

Tags: html

I have two select tags, one with fruit and town options, and the other select list contains fruit names and town names. The question is when I select a fruit in the first select tag,only fruit names appear when I click on the second select tag.

Comment: why dont u just try margin right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon after the `&nbsp` -> `&nbsp;`.

However I suggest using CSS. You can specify the margins around the `<select>` like so

```
style="margin: 5px"
```

This will set the margins around all four sides of the element to `5px`. If you want more fine-tuning, use `margin-left`, `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, and/or `margin-right`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `&nbsp;` - with a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set like this

```
<select><option value="1">123</option></select>&nbsp;<select><option value="2">12344</option></select>
```

OR

```
<select><option value="1">123</option></select><br/><select><option value="2">12344</option></select>
```

OR

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px;width:100%;" align="left"><select><option value="1">123</option></div>
```

12344

Many types u can set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code looks like

```
<select>.....</select><select>......</select>
```

You could either add some margin spacing using css or add a span around each and use padding/margin.

Answer (score -1):

You could do `<br />` instead of the `&nbsp;`

Comment: the OP asked for "in the same row"

Comment: `<br />` will break to the next line. Which is probably not his intention.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Sorry, it's pretty early... Then I'd just suggest `margin-right: Xpx`.

Comment: @SachinJalkotkar Here, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/hma66/ it's working here. If it doesn't work for you then please post your HTML and CSS so I can troubleshoot from there.